# mkfs.vfat creates multiple MBR signatures

Tags: partition, mbr

I am creating a FAT32 partition from a file image.

My commands are as follows:

Create a 2MB file image.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=fatfs.img bs=1024 count=2048
```

To create the filesystem I use:

```
mkfs.vfat -n "Test volume" -F 32 -v fatfs.img
```

When I open the fatfs.img in a hex editor I see boot signatures 0x55 0xAA in the first 512 bytes. The offset from 0x1BE i.e. the partition table data entry is empty. I see 3 more 0x55 0xAA signatures at 512 byte offsets. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> the partition table data entry is empty […] What am I missing?

The fact that you did *nothing at all* to partition your image file, not running a partition table editor tool of any sort, and that instead you've created your image file as a *whole-disc volume* formatted as FAT32.

Comment: Thanks. I did a really silly mistake there. Also I found that FAT32 has MBR replicated to prevent single point of failure. That explains the MBR repeat at sector 6. Only one problem is I don't find the 3rd sector ending with 0x55AA.